# Vapor project swift run App serve --env production does not work

Tags: production-environment, vapor, server-side-swift

I follow the Vapor doc and try to deploy my project. I tried to run
`swift run App serve --env production`
or
`.build/release/App serve --env production`

> [Vapor] ConsoleKit.ConsoleError(identifier: "unknownInput", reason: "Input not recognized: --env production")

And then I check the App serve -h. There is not --env.

> .build/release/App serve [--hostname,-H] [--port,-p] [--bind,-b]
> [--unix-socket]
>
> Begins serving the app over HTTP.
>
> Options:
> hostname Set the hostname the server will run on.
> port Set the port the server will run on.
> bind Convenience for setting hostname and port together.   unix-socket Set the path for the unix domain socket file the server
> will bind to.

Does anyone deploy a Vapor4 project on production environment successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that my entry point file is "main.swift". But a file named main.swift can't have an @main attribute.

The key is you CANNOT use main.swift as the filename of the entrypoint.

Comment: I'm fairly certain if you just generate a project using their CLI tool, it generates a `main.swift` which runs just fine.

Comment: @JackLeow You can try `swift build -c release` and then `.build/release/App serve --env production `

Comment: Here's my application - https://github.com/jackgene/presentation-service-swift - I did rename the runnable target to `presentation-service` because that's what I wanted to call it, but you'll see that it runs just fine.

The README also references how the project was initially created using the `vapor` CLI tool.

Comment: Ah, I initialized my application using Vapor 4.0, just tried the latest version, and it sets things up differently now.

Comment: If it's any help [this](https://github.com/jackgene/presentation-service-swift/blob/main/Sources/Run/main.swift) is what the Vapor 4 generated `main.swift` looks like, if you must use `main.swift`, though I'd just stick to what Vapor generates.

Comment: @JackLeow Thanks a lot! I changed the main.swift to entrypoint.swift. Everything is perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

I believe Vapor applications by default has two targets, `App` and `Run`, where `Run` is supposed to be the entrypoint. What happens if you run:

```
swift run Run serve --env production
```